# gsed: command not found on macOS with Homebrew

Tags: command-line, osx, path, homebrew

I am using oh my zsh. I am not able to use some commands which I could do on ubuntu for e.g.. \s in regular expressions. I installed home-brew and then `brew install gnu-sed --default-names` but still I am unable to used sed command. My $PATH variable is a bit messed up and I am not sure how to correct it.

```
/Users/ishansrivastava/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

What should I do so that I can use all gnu commands without hassle on my Mac?Also please give me the list of commands on which I have to use gnu command instead of default for e.g.. `gsed` instead of `sed` etc.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003570/how-to-use-gnu-sed-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003570/how-to-use-gnu-sed-on-mac-os-x),  if installing GNU `sed` using Homebrew with `--with-default-names`, then it is installed as `/usr/local/bin/sed`.

Without `--with-default-names`, it will be installed as `/usr/local/bin/gsed`.

If installed as `sed`, then it depends on your `$PATH` what `sed` binary gets picked up when you execute `sed`. If your `$PATH` is as you have described, then GNU `sed` should have precedence over the native macOS `sed`.

Note that the shell may have cached the location of the `sed` command already if you have used the command on the command line previously in the same shell session. You may then use `rehash` in `zsh` to clear that cache, or open a new terminal.

When a system provides a native `sed` implementation that is not GNU `sed`, then it is often better to install GNU `sed` as `gsed` to not break existing scripts relying on behaviour specific to the native `sed`.  This is why the default behaviour with Homebrew on macOS is to install GNU `sed` as `gsed`. This is also the default way to name GNU `sed` (and GNU tools in general) on other BSD systems.

Comment: i solved it. Apparently it installed in `usr/local/Cellar/gnu-sed/4.4/bin`. I added to the path. Still i would have liked to use gsed instead of changing what my actual sed did.

Comment: @IshanSrivastava I'm no Homebrew user, but wouldn't installing _without_ `--with-default-names` allow you to use GNU Sed as `gsed`?

Comment: i installed it with default names. i finally get you. sorry for the trouble. but why did it get installed in such an awkward path as mine?

Comment: @IshanSrivastava Some info here: http://rkulla.blogspot.se/2014/03/the-path-to-homebrew.html